# Re-installing another version

Tags: lubuntu

I just managed to install ubuntu vers 14.04.1 alongside windows 7, all works ok but it is so SLOW I tried a different video driver, with some improvement, but not much, I would like to re-install a lighter version like the latest lubuntu as I think it is just a lack of resources issue, the PC is a small shuttle (IDEQ) with an AMD sempron only 1GB of memory so I think I am asking a bit much of it.
How do I remove or replace the existing Ubuntu 14.04.1 with the lighter Lubuntu 14.04?
without messing up the win 7 setup?
I have the lubuntu image on a USB stick with the loader but have not found a way to get it to overwrite the existing installation.
Thanks..

G.

Comment: I would say to simply wipe the partition where you just installed ubuntu and install lubuntu from the USB stick you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an installable disk the same way you made one for ubuntu, either make it a usb stick or a cd...      http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/     has minimum requirements as well as lubuntu, when you run throught the set up the installer is the same as the one for ubuntu so it will be framiliar to you - dureing the setup it will recognize that there is a version of ubuntu already installed and will give you the option of over writing that installation only -  i recently did this going from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu studio 14.04..   i am running hp laptop dual booted with win 8.1